# Infragistics UltraGrid cell different color per word

Tags: infragistics, ultrawingrid

Is it possible to change the color of a word in a text value of a Ultragrid Cell? 
for example: `7m + 5m + 7m2` where `7m2` is in red color.

I am going to implement this in my windows application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the [Style](https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/infragistics4.win.ultrawingrid.v16.2~infragistics.win.ultrawingrid.ultragridcolumn~style) of the column to FormattedText / FormattedTextEditor. Then you need to set the value of the Cell to some [formatted text](https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/winformattedlinklabel-formatting-text-and-hyperlinks). In your case you could set the value to something like this:

```
var cellValue = "7m + 5m + <span style=\"color:Red;\">7m<span style=\"vertical - align:Super;\">2</span></span>";
```